# Select non duplicate records from a hive join query

Tags: sql, hadoop, join, hive, hiveql

I have the following Hive query:

```
select *
from A
left outer join B
on A.ID = B.ID
where B.ID IS NULL
```

The result produces duplicate data but I need only non-duplicate records.

After some research, I tried the below query:

```
select *
from (
    select *
    from A
    left outer join on B
    where A.ID = B.ID AND B.ID IS NULL ) join_result
group by jojn_result.ID
```

It's showing an ambiguous column reference ID error.

I do not have the columns name of table A.

Please help me to identify the solution to this .

Thank you .

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results...

Comment: I used the same query with the exception of using parenthesis around the ON clause and succesfully get just the records from table A      select *
from A
left outer join B
on (A.ID = B.ID)
where B.ID IS NULL

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . How about `select`:

```
Select A.*
from A left outer join
     B
     on A.ID = B.ID
where B.ID IS NULL;
```

I removed the `B` columns because they are not needed.

Comment: Thank you Gordon .  Distinct is not supported in hive version 0.14 . I have issue with source systems , that's the reasons I am getting duplicates .  I just removed distinct it's worked

Answer (score 0):

One of your join columns may have `NULL` values. Whenever there is `NULL` in any of the join key values, it will skip that column. Try replacing the `NULL` with some default value while joining using `NVL` or `COALESCE`. I was looking for same answer and saw your post here. But there was no solution. But since i found the solution I just wanted to post here so that someone can benefit.

```sql
select *
from A
left outer join B
on coalesce(A.ID,000) = coalesce(B.ID,000)
where B.ID IS NULL
```